# High Bias in 1dimensional CNN with high training Loss

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I am working on a project where I have to classify the good and bad packets. I am modelling my data with 1 dimensional CNN u where i have to predict good packet(0) and malicious packets(1,2,3), i have upsample the data with class_weight parameter while training the model. I have reshaped my data(6,1) and i have used a Conv1d layers where the first one has 124,second one has 64 and the third one has 48 layers. In each middle layer I have used a kernel_size = 5, padding =same, and activation function relu. Afterthat I have used a Flatten, with BatchNormalization and I have added a two Dense layers with 128 and 64 respectively with activation function RELU. The output layer has the number of classes(4) and activation function softmax. However the model has a high Bias and the training loss is much higher than the validation loss. I really need help...
Thanks in advance!

My original data has 168000, however i am first trying to get the model working on small data[image]

Results of the model.[image]

Comment: Hi @Ivan. With this little information, the number of possible causes is very big and the chance of getting a good answer is low. Please consider giving more details and showing the source code.

Comment: I have updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: Without the source, there are many details that would be needed to identify the cause: loss function, optimizer, hyperparameters like the learning rate, etc.

Comment: I have just added the source. Thanks!

Comment: Never post code as a screenshot. Try to modify the post including the snippet of code as in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1D convolutions are normally used in sequence data, but your data seems tabular. Also, your data is discrete (ports, IP addresses, flags) converted to real numbers, which is not an appropriate input to neural nets. What is the rationale for using such a network on such type of data?

Comment: Could you suggest me what model would be the best to be used for this tpye of data?